# DB Connection leak when Using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch, hikaricp

I have a Spring Batch application with JpaPagingItemReader which use SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.
And i use AbstractRoutingDataSource to be able using 2 datasources.

My datasource config from guides.

```
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

    final DataSource readDataSource = buildDataSource(READ_HIKARI_POOL, readProperties);
    final DataSource writeDataSource = buildDataSource(WRITE_HIKARI_POOL, writeProperties);

    targetDataSources.put(RoutingDataSource.READ, readDataSource);
    targetDataSources.put(RoutingDataSource.WRITE, writeDataSource);

    return new RoutingDataSource(targetDataSources, readDataSource);
  }

  private DataSource buildDataSource(final String poolName,
                                     final AuroraProperties auroraProperties) {
    final HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

    hikariConfig.setPoolName(poolName);
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(auroraProperties.getUrl());
    hikariConfig.setUsername(auroraProperties.getUsername());
    hikariConfig.setPassword(auroraProperties.getPassword());
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(auroraProperties.getDriver());
    hikariConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(LEAK_DETECTION_THRESHOLD_MS);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);

    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
  }
```

Also,

```
@Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(
      final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return transactionManager;
  }
```

And

```
@Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
  public TaskExecutor asyncExecutor() {
    final SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(MAX_ASYNC_TASK_COUNT);
    taskExecutor.setTaskDecorator(mdcTaskDecorator);

    return taskExecutor;
  }
```

The code of Jpa paging item reader is default.
All works, but i have a connection leak.
After each JOB i have 1 connection leaked on Jpa PagingItemReader in place

```
final List<Model> queryResult = query.getResultList();
```

The stacktrace from leaked connection is

```
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at com.test.service.EnricherJpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(EnricherJpaPagingItemReader.java:122)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.test.service.EnrichedJpaPagingItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c44a11bc.read(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:94)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:161)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:119)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:113)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
    at com.test.common.config.MdcTaskDecorator.lambda$decorate$0(MdcTaskDecorator.java:20)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottlingRunnable.run(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:275)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EnrichedJpaPagingItemReader is my copy of JpaPagingItemReader which i can debug. When i commend line with query.getResultList(), then i got no connection leak. I have 5 jpa repositories which are triggered after this one and all fine. All return connections.
Guys, can you help me. How can i fix this?

Comment: `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does not reuse threads, which could be the cause of your issue. Have you tried to use a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`?

Comment: Yes, tried. Some update. THe problem is not in AsyncTaskExecutor. JpaPagingItemReader is not returning connection after job

Comment: How did you came to that conclusion? Can you isolate the issue and provide a failing test? If you believe this is a bug in the `JpaPagingItemReader`, please open an issue on [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/BATCH).

Comment: JpaPagingItemReader in Spring Batch have query.getResultList(). SO, if i will comment this line and leave enrichers (jpa repositories), Hikari connections are back to poll (i sed debug logging). If not, 1 connection is not returning and stay active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with changing JpaPagingItemReader to JdbcPagingItemReader